# Chisel synchronous read memory

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm trying to generate the verilog for a memory with a synchronous read with the following chisel

```
val my_mem = Mem(Bits(width=64), 4096, seqRead=true)
val read_data = Reg(Bits(width=64))
when(io.re) {
 read_data := my_mem(io.addr)
}
io.ret_data := read_data
```

However, this generates verilog with this

```
wire[63:0] T1;
reg [63:0] read_data;
assign T1 = my_mem[io_addr];

always @(posedge clk) begin
if(io_re) begin
  read_data <= T1;
end
```

What I am doing wrong to get chisel to generate verilog that has the memory read inside the always block?

Comment: Isn't the read already inside the always block?

Comment: The read of the memory is the assign statement, then it just gets registered in the read_data flop, right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question, seems it seems to me that Chisel did in fact generate a synchronous memory.  Are your synthesis tools not properly picking up that pattern and generating the appropriate hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chisel manual state the proper way to create a synchronous memory is to register the ADDRESS, not the read data.  Although slightly unintuitive, with register re-timing, it is conceptually the same thing.

```
 val my_mem    = Mem(Bits(width=64), 4096, seqRead=true)
 val reg_raddr = Reg(UInt())
 val rdata     = my_mem(reg_raddr)
 when (io.re) { reg_raddr := io.addr }
```

Which generates this:

```
assign io_out = T0;
assign T0 = my_mem[reg_raddr];

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(io_re) begin
    reg_raddr <= io_addr;
  end
end
```

The data read is not in the always block, but I don't believe that is necessary for the synthesis tools to pick up that you want a synchronous memory.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Your right, I believe that the synthesis tool only requires that the read-address is registered inside the same module.